# I'm trying to add a mailto link to my website; its works fine offline, but online it gives me a 404 error

Tags: html, dreamweaver, mailto

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 to built a basic webiste for a friend; 
On the contact page, I'm trying to add a mailto link ; it does not work wen I upload into Filezilla but works fine when I try it offline (I use Firefox 52.0.1 and the host is Godaddy)).
Here is the code for the page:

[image: code]

And if I click online on the link, I got that page :

[image: screenshot01]

Any clue of what is happening?

A4

Comment: First of all, don't post an image of your code - post actual code. Also please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I could not post the actual code ; as a new member I had some posting restrictions, and somes links in my code would not leave me publish it...

Answer (score 0):

I've visited your website with Firefox and Chrome. Everything works fine for me.

From your screenshot it looks, like the error you're getting is because you've forgotten about putting "mailto:" in front of your e-mail, but I can see in the code, that it's there, and of course it works for me.

My guess is that first you didn't add "mailto:', then added it, but for some reason Firefox is still showing you the old version of your website. **To force complete refresh on Mac, you can press: Command + Shift + R. This should solve your problem.**

Comment: Thank you; it seems that the link worked lated on the day; I wonder if there is a delay between the moment I download files in Filezilla and the time they get activated online. I have the same problem with other pages where I use lightbox...
Thanks again!